# Buenas, soy principiante en python y tengo la duda de por que cuando clickeo el segundo numero o carácter se borra el primero?

Tags: python

por que cuando hago click en otro numero o digito se borra el anterior, si primero clickeo el numero 1 y luego el 2 se borra el 1, soy principiante en python y estaba desarrollando una calculadora con pyqt5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: El método se llama "setText", "Establecer Texto". El nombre de los métodos suele comunicar lo que hacen. En este caso, estás cambiando el texto anterior por el nuevo.